# Does it change the dialogs or options depending on the leader?

Tags: doom-and-destiny

In the Tactics menu you can change the leader of the party, being the one at front while walking around, and the one interacting with the people and objects.

Does the selected leader changes the dialogs in the game? Or more important thing: Does one leader over another grant more possibilities (like reaching a hidden area or obtaining an item)?

Comment: I'm only aware of changing the leader which changes your position bonuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few scenarios where an NPC's response will change depending on the character in the lead (a few Powers/Skills are acquired this way), and there are also a couple bonus dungeons that only allow access with specific characters leading, but for 95% of the game it only affects the position bonuses.